# input type="file" using link in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to emulate `<input type="file">` and get a file browser using a link and jQuery?

I've tried to find a tutorial to do this, but a search on google doesn't show me any answers. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your end goal here? What are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

`file` inputs let to browse your disk, etc to select a file.  This can't be emulated with any other standard HTML/JS technique.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved similar in the past but its a bit of a hack:

- Put a normal fileupload on the page.
- Make it completely transparent(using opacity - don't change it's visibility to hidden)
- Position your link under the file upload browse button.

When the user thinks they're clicking on the link, they will actually click the browse button.

Its horrible, but I don't know of another way.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do. If you ever want to style the input file element without having to use Flash instead, this is the way!

Comment: @BjarkeCK: Yep - that's the idea. Its ages since I did it though so mine wasn't as nice as that - mine was pre jQuery for a start.

Comment: Note that this will create issues while using a website with a keyboard, and a few accesibility issues as well.

Comment: @Hugo: Valid point - its a consideration to be borne in mind.